# Apropos-like documentation in a new window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for a non-interactive function which will take a name, and display its documentation in a new window, honoring the 'links' quoted in the docstring.

All I could find is:

- `apropos`, which needs an interactive, intermediate step, and
- `documentation`, which returns plain strings, ignoring the mentioned 'links'.

Is there a function that brings the best of both worlds? If not, how to compose it (i.e. generate links from words quoted `like this')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help functions can be called non-interactively too:

```
(describe-function 'forward-char)
```

This displays the documentation in a new window (the variable `help-window-select` controls where it is displayed).

If you want a function which works both for functions and variables then this is a possible approach:

```
(defun my-describe-stuff (symbol)
  (if (functionp symbol)
      (describe-function symbol)
    (if (boundp symbol)
        (describe-variable symbol))))
```

Comment: Terrific! Thank you very much Tom.

Comment: If you call an interactive function then you can press `C-x ESC ESC` to find out how Emacs translates it into Elisp code. That's what I did here. I invoked `C-h f` with a function name and then pressed `C-x ESC ESC` to get the relevant elisp code.

Comment: Emacs never ceases to amaze me.